# search data structure with custom distance on histograms

Tags: search, matching, feature-extraction, nearest-neighbor

I have a list of k-dimensional features M. I want to find in this list the nearest item to a query feature A. Feature comparison is not directly based on a common metric (such as Euclidean or Symmetric Chi2). Rather, the comparison between feature A and feature B is done as follows : compute the distance (any common metric) between feature A and B'. B' is obtained from circular shifting of B. Since the features are k-dimensional, we obtain k-1 distances between A and B, and the comparison function returns the lowest.

Considering my comparison function above, is it possible to optimize the NN search with an appropriate algorithm or data structure ?

Comment: One key point is whether your distance is uniformly increasing. E.g. if B is further away using a Minkowski distance (such as Euclidean), is it also always further away using your distance? If yes, then any multi-dim index should work. If not, then no index that I am aware of will work. Maybe you can clarify, is the circular shifting (I assume "rotation"?) around A or another point? Why does one dimension disappear, is it because you rotate around A until you hit 0 for one axis? If it is around around another point (C), is the radius small; if yes, can you index the bounding box of C's sphere?

Comment: the circular or cyclic shift is meant to make the feature matching rotation invariant. Assume a robot with pose p1, feature A is an histogram which quantizes the physical 2D corners around p1. The histogram construction is based on a polar grid with its angular origin set to robot's local frame. B is a feature obtained from pose p2. If poses p1 and p2 are close, we should have approximately similar corners around each position. However, because the orientation of the robot (sensor) in p1 is not necessarily similar to that of p2, A and B might be relatively shifted.

Comment: If we compare A and B using Euclidean distance for instance, the result might suggest a mismatch between them. Therefore, I need to compare A with all shifted versions of B. The shifting is cyclic. For instance, the sequence ABC if shifted once would give CAB, shifted twice gives BCA. We do not need to shift it three times since that would give ABC. that's why we need k-1 cyclic shifts for a vector of k-dimensions.

Comment: This means that A and B can be further away using an Euclidean distance, but my distance might find a shifted version of B that is closer to A using an Euclidean distance as well.

Comment: Maybe you can add the clarification to the questions. I do not understand the robot example but I don't think it is relevant. I also do not understand the cyclic shift (in the question you call it circular shift), maybe add an example or drawing? 
I think you misunderstood my key point: Let's call your distance function d_robot() and euclidean distance d_euclid(). If d_robot(a,b) >= d_robot(a,c) if and only if d_euclid(a,b) >= d_euclid(a,c) for all thinkable a,b,c then you can use any index. Otherwise I don't think there is any index that will work.

Comment: Also, maybe discuss what you have tried. Did you already try any index? Did it work? If not, how/why did it fail?
If you didn't try anything, maybe you can discuss why it may or may not work with a conventional index?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you with the robot example. Also circular and cyclic shifting are the same to me. Please refer in the example I've given above. It consists of shifting elements of a vector in a circular fashion in a direction. For instance, if I shift to the right the vector with elements {A,B,C} one time it gives {C, A, B}. I do not know how to prove that : d_robot(a,b) >= d_robot(a,c) if and only if d_euclid(a,b) >= d_euclid(a,c).

Comment: I am confused by your example, are those vectors coordinates, i.e. is vector A=(1,2,3) and B=(4,5,6) and then changes to B'=(5,6,4)? Or do you have vectors that somehow contain coordinates, i.e. vector V={A,B,C) where A is a coordinate, B changes to B' and C is something else? It would be helpful if you could just write down your distance function and provide an example.
Also: You don't need to prove the theorem, just use intuition.monotonically increasing with metric distance.

Comment: The vectors are not coordinates. It is just an example. Actually they are histograms is the form of vectors.